# Did the Fat Lady ever question why sometimes people would leave the Gryffindor common room unseen?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry often uses his Invisibility Cloak to lurk around the castle in the dead of night. He almost always leaves the common room with the Cloak on, instead of putting it on afterwards. One example:

> Harry and Ron waited for the distant sound of two dormitory doors closing before **seizing the cloak, throwing it over themselves, and climbing through the portrait hole**

Doesn't the Fat Lady get curious as to why she see's no one leave? Did she tell any teachers about this possible safety hazard?

Especially later in the series when Sirius was on the loose.

Comment: You could also ask why she let so many students (Hermione, Colin and esp. Ginny) go out wandering on their own in *Chamber of Secrets*, when an attacker was on the loose and picking off students.

Comment: She was often drunk, or just asleep and probably couldn't be bothered. Besides, with ghosts, poltergeists and other magical things going on, she probably wasn't very concerned. Also, she's the equivalent of a hall monitor; just there to make sure the kids from separate houses don't mix, not to investigate crimes etc.

Comment: I seem to remember there is an instance when he questions Harry and lies to him that the password has changed at midnight.  That might have been only because she was irritated to be woken up at night, not concerned about the students.

Comment: @alexwlchan - that seems like an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found one example where she notices Harry sneaking out. When he goes to find the Mirror of Erised in *Philosopher’s Stone*, she seems a bit surprised:

> “Who’s there?” squawked the Fat Lady. Harry said nothing. He walked quickly down the corridor.

But we never see any evidence that a teacher (Dumbledore aside) was aware that somebody might have been wandering the castle at night.

Remember that invisibility cloaks are fairly rare, and it is fairly unlikely that a student would have one. At the very least, she won't be expecting it. There's no real evidence that anybody has left the tower (if Harry was careful with his footsteps.) So what would she say? The portrait hole opened, somebody went out, but I didn't see or hear anything. Great story.

I’m sure she can think of plausible explanations for these events that don’t involve super-rare invisibility cloaks. Perhaps it was a first-year playing a prank. Perhaps somebody was about to come out, but remembered something they’d left inside. And so on.

That’s the charitable interpretation.

The other interpretation is that she doesn’t notice or care, because she’s just not very good at her job. She gets drunk or falls asleep on the job, gets tetchy with students, and will refuse to open if she’s not in a good mood. Hardly the hallmarks of a good security guard.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a tough question.

**Digging from the past:**

> When Molly Prewett was a student, she returned to Gryffindor Tower at 4 in the morning after taking a late night stroll with her then boyfriend (now husband), Arthur Weasley, and they both got a telling-off from the Fat Lady.

Found this at http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fat_Lady.

Based on this, we know she used to check students coming into and getting out of Gryffindor Tower. From this I can draw following conclusion.

1. She might have changed over the years.
2. Harry Potter was very may be she had a soft spot for Harry and his friends.